Disable text input autocomplete in Music
The text input autocomplete in the Music app is really intrusive. Most apps won't replace your text unless you choose to use the autocomplete suggestions, but Music replaces what you typed or simply adds in text without any additional input. This is in places like get info or editing rules for a smart playlist. It will substitute existing values in place of what you are typing. This is really annoying if you want to type something that doesn't exist yet, but partially matches. I would love to figure out how to disable this.
Example of trying to type "heaters" where in one case it adds a whole bunch of text after the "h", the other where it leaves me with a capital "H" I have to go back and fix.


What you are looking for can be easily solved in most macOS Apps by turning off automatic substitutions or uncheck Correct Spelling automatically. However, Autocompletion in Smart Playlists is a feature and can not be disabled. Apple Music suggests artist names based on your Music Library. Actually, it helps you to type less and shows instantly which data matches your database.
It is not the answer you are looking for. The only workaround I can recommend is to ignore any Autocompletion and keep typing in your preferred artist or album name. Alternatively copy and paste your keyword from Text Edit or any text editor.

Yeah, this is some kind of extra intrusive autocomplete that is different from the normal OS one. It's especially annoying since it goes backward behind your cursor and replaces text you've already typed. You can work around it by selecting text and typing over as shown in the video, but that's just annoying. I think unfortunately the answer here may just be that there is no way to turn it off.
